# Making a character array rotate its cells left/right n times

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I'm totally new here but I heard a lot about this site and now that I've been accepted for a 7 months software development 'bootcamp' I'm sharpening my C knowledge for an upcoming test.

I've been assigned a question on a test that I've passed already, but I did not finish that question and it bothers me quite a lot.

The question was a task to write a program in C that moves a character (char) array's cells by 1 to the left (it doesn't quite matter in which direction for me, but the question specified left). And I also took upon myself NOT to use a temporary array/stack or any other structure to hold the entire array data during execution.

So a 'string' or array of chars containing '0' '1' '2' 'A' 'B' 'C' will become
'1' '2' 'A' 'B' 'C' '0' after using the function once.

Writing this was no problem, I believe I ended up with something similar to:

```
void ArrayCharMoveLeft(char arr[], int arrsize, int times) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= arrsize ; i++) {
        ArraySwap2CellsChar(arr, i, i+1);
    }
}
```

As you can see the function is somewhat modular since it allows to input how many times the cells need to move or shift to the left. I did not implement it, but that was the idea.

As far as I know there are 3 ways to make this:

1. Loop ArrayCharMoveLeft times times. This feels instinctively inefficient.
2. Use recursion in ArrayCharMoveLeft. This should resemble the first solution, but I'm not 100% sure on how to implement this.
3. This is the way I'm trying to figure out: No loop within loop, no recursion, no temporary array, the program will know how to move the cells x times to the left/right without any issues.

The problem is that after swapping say N times of cells in the array, the remaining array size - times are sometimes not organized. For example:

Using ArrayCharMoveLeft with 3 as times with our given array mentioned above will yield
ABC021 instead of the expected value of ABC012.

I've run the following function for this:

```
int i;
char* lastcell;
if (!(times % arrsize))
{
    printf("Nothing to move!\n");
    return;
}
times = times % arrsize;
// Input checking. in case user inputs multiples of the array size, auto reduce to array size reminder
for (i = 0; i < arrsize-times; i++) {
    printf("I = %d ", i);
    PrintArray(arr, arrsize);
    ArraySwap2CellsChar(arr, i, i+times);
}
```

As you can see the for runs from 0 to array size - times. If this function is used, say with an array containing 14 chars. Then using times = 5 will make the for run from 0 to 9, so cells 10 - 14 are NOT in order (but the rest are).

The worst thing about this is that the remaining cells always maintain the sequence, but at different position. Meaning instead of 0123 they could be 3012 or 2301... etc.

I've run different arrays on different times values and didn't find a particular pattern such as "if remaining cells = 3 then use ArrayCharMoveLeft on remaining cells with times = 1).

It always seem to be 1 out of 2 options: the remaining cells are in order, or shifted with different values. It seems to be something similar to this:
times    shift+direction to allign
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        1R
5        3R
6        5R
7        3R
8        1R
the numbers change with different times and arrays. Anyone got an idea for this?
even if you use recursion or loops within loops, I'd like to hear a possible solution. Only firm rule for this is not to use a temporary array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouaw! What a long explanation for a problem that seems so simple. Do not swap two adjacent cells but move a cell directly to his correct position. You may also take advantage of using [memmove](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) which handle overlapping areas.

Comment: This is just a generalized form of swapping two values, and the solution is essentially the same:  (1) Save `a[0]` in a temp (2) loop, setting `a[0]` to `a[1]`, then `a[1]` to `a[2]` etc.  Finally, set `a[n-1]` to the temp.  If you store to any array element more than once (as would be the case if you used pairwise swaps), then your solution is bad.

Comment: If you want to shift by more than one, the same solution works, except in that case you may need to run it multiple times (offsetting the starting point by one each time).  The number of times it needs to run is GCD(n, amt), where n is the array length and amt is the shift amount.

Comment: In the real world you leave the array alone and just start from an index other than 0. Moving data around is inefficient.

Comment: You can remove the first one caracter and reserve him to an temporary variable ,then you shift all caracters to the left and you stock the temporary variable in the last case of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If irrespective of efficiency or simplicity for the purpose of studying you want to use only exchanges of two array elements with `ArraySwap2CellsChar`, you can keep your loop with some adjustment. As you noted, the given `for (i = 0; i < arrsize-times; i++)` loop leaves the last *times* elements out of place. In order to correctly place all elements, the loop condition has to be `i < arrsize-1` (one less suffices because if every element but the last is correct, the last one must be right, too). Of course when `i` runs nearly up to `arrsize`, `i+times` can't be kept as the other swap index; instead, the correct index `j` of the element which is to be put at index `i` has to be computed. This computation turns out somewhat tricky, due to the element having been swapped already from its original place. Here's a modified variant of your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < arrsize-1; i++)
{
    printf("i = %d ", i);
    int j = i+times;
    while (arrsize <= j) j %= arrsize, j += (i-j+times-1)/times*times;
    printf("j = %d ", j);
    PrintArray(arr, arrsize);
    ArraySwap2CellsChar(arr, i, j);
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. I've run your modified loop with a couple different values, and I noticed it worked perfectly! Except when: Times = 3, the output result was 3456789ABCDE2 (while the original array is 0123456789ABCDE), so you see cells in positions 0,1 are completely omitted from the final array. The same happened with times = 4. result is: 56789ABCDE4 (0,1,2,3 omitted). Can you explain what exactly the while line does? Never seen while being used like this (unless its just a code block?).

Comment: Regarding the wrong results: I think you passed the wrong `arrsize` 16 to the function, instead of the correct 15, didn't you? - The _while line_ is an ordinary `while` loop which executes the two comma-separated expressions after the `(…)` condition as long as that is true; we could also put the expressions in `{` `}`, which would look more familiar.

Comment: I see, so the while syntax really shortens a normal code block syntax. Regarding the array size, the function uses the correct array size of 15 (0 - E). The for loop runs from 0 to arrsize-1 which is 14 (last cell index). i = 12 j = 12 3456789ABCDE012 .... 3456789ABCDE2 2 iterations before i reaches 14 yields us the correct result for times = 3. it's different on times = 4, but same concept. on times =4 the answer is achieved when  i=11.

Comment: How do you mean _i reaches 14_ - do you get an output `i = 14 …`? With `arrsize` 15, it must not happen that _i reaches 14_ within the loop, because the condition is `i < arrsize-1`, i. e. the loop body is not executed for i = 14.

Comment: I'll dig into this a bit later this evening if I got the time. As of now you're proposing the most suitable solution for the problem I had! I appreciate your help. I do apologize for everyone if I made the problem appear big, as it is simple by nature, but the solution I look for is very specific, meaning I know how to solve the problem, I'm just looking for alternatives for the sake of learning and comparing them.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have done it. When I said "i = 14" back then I think I meant J, instead. Regardless, the missing cells were a result of your code calling ArraySwap2CellsChar when both indexes (i and J) are the same. Not sure why, but my function deletes the cell if it tries to swap it with itself. A simple "if" statement fixed it.  I'm still not sure WHY the while loop works, specifically with the 2 expressions that follow it, but it does. If you can clarify how it swaps the array cells without exiting it's memory range I would really appreciate it. Thanks, in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question right - _it swaps the array cells without exiting it's memory range_ simply because i as well as j are within the range 0 to arrsize−1 (j is because the `while (arrsize <= j)` loop is not exited before j < arrsize).

Comment: I mean, why use j %= arrsize, j += (i-j+times-1)/times*times? j becomes the remainder of j from arrsize (assuming arrsize is always bigger than j, it stays the same, like saying 3%9 which leaves us with 3. so as long arrsize > j then the first expression does nothing, why do we need it? And what does the 2nd expression do? it's quite complicated, J is increased by i-j+times-1 divided by times squared? How did you come up with this?

Comment: But it's not true that _arrsize is always bigger than j_, since initially `j = i+times` and `i+times` can be up to arrsize−2+times. In case arrsize is bigger than j initially, the loop isn't entered at all. - In the _2nd expression_, it's not _i-j+times-1 divided by times squared_; multiply/divide associate from left to right, so it's (i-j+times-1 divided by times) multiplied by times, i. e. rounding i-j up to the next multiple of times. This serves to compute the index where an already swapped element to the left of i has been placed. I needed quite some trial and error to come up with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use standard library functions `memcpy`, `memmove`, etc as they are very optimized for your platform.
2. Use the correct type for sizes - `size_t` not `int`

```
char *ArrayCharMoveLeft(char *arr, const size_t arrsize, size_t ntimes) 
{
    ntimes %= arrsize;
    if(ntimes)
    {
        char temp[ntimes];
        memcpy(temp, arr, ntimes);
        memmove(arr, arr + ntimes, arrsize - ntimes);
        memcpy(arr + arrsize - ntimes, temp, ntimes);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

But you want it without the temporary array (more memory efficient, very bad performance-wise):

```
char *ArrayCharMoveLeft(char *arr, size_t arrsize, size_t ntimes) 
{
    ntimes %= arrsize;
    while(ntimes--)
    {
        char temp = arr[0];
        memmove(arr, arr + 1, arrsize - 1);
        arr[arrsize -1] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/od68dKTWq
https://godbolt.org/z/noah9zdYY

Comment: Thought it was a given the answer shouldn't use external functions from strings.h. Also, without any temporary variables to store any array information. Using I for counter is fine and storing the size of the array is also okay. Other than that the array can change within itself like using swap2cells but not using any external variable to temporarily hold 1 cell value.

Comment: @SamSegal write memmove yourself. You got the answer and you complain. BTW there is no way to swap values without temporary variables.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but you're wrong. void ArraySwap2CellsChar(char arr[], int indexA, int indexB) {

 if (arr[indexA] + arr[indexB] < 255)
 {
  arr[indexA] = arr[indexA] + arr[indexB];
  arr[indexB] = arr[indexA] - arr[indexB];
  arr[indexA] = arr[indexA] - arr[indexB];
 }
 else
 {
  arr[indexA] = arr[indexA] - arr[indexB];
  arr[indexB] = arr[indexA] + arr[indexB];
  arr[indexA] = arr[indexA] + arr[indexB];
 }
} That's how you swap 2 cells of a char array in C, I wrote it myself without using any external libraries. I'm not complaining, I just didn't get the answer I hoped.

Comment: @SamSegal do you think that this temp sum is not stored anywhere? What if `arr` has a `long long` or `double` type. This kind of "optimizations" should be avoided at any price

Comment: there ain't no 'temp'. You multiply the cells and divide in such a way that you don't use an extra cell to swap their values. Maybe not the most practical use, but the least memory-consuming I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if it's common to share a full working code here or not, since this is literally my first question asked here, so I'll refrain from doing so assuming the idea is answering specific questions, and not providing an example solution for grabs (which might defeat the purpose of studying and exploring C). This argument is backed by the fact that this specific task is derived from a programing test  used by a programing course and it's purpose is to filter out applicants who aren't fit for intense 7 months training in software development. If you still wish to see my code, message me privately.

So, with a great amount of help from @**Armali** I'm happy to announce the question is answered! Together we came up with a function that takes an array of characters in C (string), and without using any previously written libraries (such as strings.h), or even a temporary array, it rotates all the cells in the array N times to the left.

Example: using ArrayCharMoveLeft() on the following array with N = 5:
Original array: 0123456789ABCDEF
Updated array: 56789ABCDEF01234
As you can see the first cell (0) is now the sixth cell (5), the 2nd cell is the 7th cell and so on. So each cell was moved to the left 5 times. The first 5 cells 'overflow' to the end of the array and now appear as the Last 5 cells, while maintaining their order.
The function works with various array lengths and N values.

This is not any sort of achievement, but rather an attempt to execute the task with as little variables as possible (only 4 ints, besides the char array, also counting the sub function used to swap the cells).

It was achieved using a nested loop so by no means its efficient runtime-wise, just memory wise, while still being self-coded functions, with no external libraries used (except stdio.h).

Refer to Armali's posted solution, it should get you the answer for this question.

Comment: It would be absolutely okay and in conformance with the Q&A scheme of this site _to share a full working code here_.